# localstack docker-compose - The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, localstack

Running localstack and app via docker-compose to dummy a s3 bucket, but getting the error:

```
"msg":"Failed to upload file /test-data/test.txt: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records."
```

If i run the app via `docker run` using valid AWS credentials, it will run successfully and connect. Any ideas what ive done wrong?

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  postbox:
    build: .
    ports: 
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - S3_BUCKET=localstack-postbox-s3
      - MESSAGE_BUS_ENDPOINT=http://localhost
      - AWS_REGION=eu-west-2
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xyz
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=aaa
      - NODE_ENV=test
    depends_on:
      - localstack
    
  localstack:
    container_name: localstack
    image: localstack/localstack:0.14.2
    ports:
      - "4566-4599:4566-4599"
    environment:
      - SERVICES=s3
    volumes:
      - ./infra/localstack:/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d

  aws:
    container_name: aws-cli
    image: amazon/aws-cli:latest
    environment:
      - AWS_REGION=eu-west-2
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xyz
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=aaa
    entrypoint: tail -f /dev/null
    depends_on:
      - localstack
      - postbox
```

Comment: Are you using an `endpoint_url` when you instantiate an aws client in your application code? Use `http://localhost:4566` to point to localstack

Comment: Hi yes, we have coded for running locally and adding the endpoint, but its still not able to see it, 

so running:

```

Comment: This seems like a networking issue to me, can you post a snippet of your application code?

Comment: had some playtime and added a aws-cli image, if i run the below from workstation i return results. If i run it from the docker aws-cli it fails, so presume its a network issue with docker-compose, from what i understood, is that the default network allows access to workstation all images etc.

```
aws s3api list-buckets --endpoint_url=http://localhost:4566
```

Updated the docker-compose in root ticket as theres not enough space here.

Comment: Adding `network_mode: "host"` on the aws-cli service allows it to run successfully for the s3api command.  But if i add it to the postbox service, it blocks me connecting to that service with localhost:8000

Answer (score 3):

Got this all working!

First ensure that endpoint_url is added for any localstack calls

Second, in the docker app ensure that any localhost calls are updated to host.docker.internal

Comment: This is an acceptable approach. Another way is to use an isolated bridged network, then expose the ports. This makes everything accessible from both hosts and containers.

Answer (score 0):

If you come here from Java land, I found using the following Java 11 code in my lambda worked for me:

```java
 /**
   * @return an instance of S3Client
   */
  public static S3Client s3Client() {
    final S3ClientBuilder builder = S3Client.builder();
    getEndpointOverride().ifPresent(builder::endpointOverride);
    return builder
            .credentialsProvider(EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.create())
            .region(Region.of(getEnvironmentVariable("AWS_REGION").orElse("us-east-1")))
            .httpClientBuilder(UrlConnectionHttpClient.builder())
            .build();
  }

  /**
   * Determine any endpoint override.
   *
   * @return Optional endpoint override value.
   */
  private static Optional<URI> getEndpointOverride() {
    Optional<URI> result = Optional.empty();
    final Optional<String> localstackHostname = getEnvironmentVariable("LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME");
    if (localstackHostname.isPresent()) {
      final Optional<String> port = getEnvironmentVariable("EDGE_PORT");
      try {
        result = Optional.of(new URI("http://" + localstackHostname.get() + ":" + port.orElse("4566")));
      } catch (final URISyntaxException e) {
        log.error("Failed to create URI", e);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  /**
   * Read environment variable.
   *
   * @param environmentVariable Variable to read.
   * @return Optional.empty() if value is not present, empty or blank.
   */
  private static Optional<String> getEnvironmentVariable(final String environmentVariable) {
    Optional<String> result = Optional.empty();
    final String value = System.getenv(environmentVariable);
    if (!Objects.isNull(value) && !value.isBlank()) {
      result = Optional.of(value);
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

see https://localstack-docs-preview-pr-444.surge.sh/references/network-troubleshooting/endpoint-url/#from-a-container-localstack-created.

```
environment:
  MAIN_DOCKER_NETWORK=<NETWORK NAME>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).